# using jquery ui keyboard plugin for ios/android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, jquery-ui

I am working on jQuery UI Virtual keyboard plugin(https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard) for ios/android web sites which will be only browsed via webview.
and I am wondering how to avoid opening IOS/Android default keyboards to use the jQuery keyboard instead.
I don't know why this happens though sometimes OS default keyboards stay invisible when I tap input text areas and only the jQuery UI keyboard will appear but sometimes both of them will show up.
Is there anyway to make the default keyboard keeping disappeared explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by myself.

1. Put `readonly` attribute into `input` tag which you want to replace keyboards
2. Change jQuery UI Virtual keyboard source

around line194

```
// Don't open if disabled
    if (base.$el.is(':disabled') || (base.$el.attr('readonly') &&
        !base.$el.hasClass('ui-keyboard-lockedinput'))) {
        base.$el.addClass('ui-keyboard-nokeyboard');
        return;
    }
```

delete the latter condition which is `(base.$el.attr('readonly') && !base.$el.hasClass('ui-keyboard-lockedinput')`

done.

then input tag with `readonly` attribute doesn't open OS default keyboards but the jquery one.